# Current drop with capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, measurement

I'm new to electronics, and there's something I can't figure out.
Can someone explain to me why, when I add C1, the current drops drastically in R3?

I was thinking that the impedance will be the same at 30 kHz, so I can't figure it out, maybe it's a low-pass effect?

[image]

---

I'd just like to add a few more details about the circuit that I should have added from the start.
I'm currently working on a circuit to measure the impedance of a liquid. To do this, I'm using the AD5933.
Initially, we only wanted to detect the presence of liquid.
At the beginning, the impedance was isolated and the circuit look like this:

[image]

After a few tests, we found that the values returned were too sensitive and went as far as saturation.
As we don't have much electronics knowledge and the board was already delivered, we decided to ground the unknown impedance to obtain better resolution. It was enough for our application but of course, the impedance value no longer made any sense.
So this configuration is the circuit I simulated above with R3 and C1 for the unknown impedance.

[image]

This works because the current decreases when there's an impedance. So you can see the presence of a liquid if there's no capacity effect (that's what I'm demonstrating by simulation).

We now want to have a more accurate circuit, so I'll go back to an isolated configuration and change the RBF value. I'll also use the additional circuit shown on the evaluation board for a high-precision measurement.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that C1 blocks the DC current in R3? C1 charges up to the "virtual" 2.5 V set by R4 and R5, and thereafter, only the AC signal drives current through R3. (It's basically a high-pass effect.)

Comment: Indeed, that's obvious, thanks you very much !

Comment: R3 and C1 are NEVER connected to the -input pin of an inverting opamp circuit.

Comment: @msch - Hi, FYI, you posted an "answer" but later confirmed that it was not the solution, just additional information. Therefore I have moved it into the question as an edit. || I'm not sure why it seems to have the same schematic twice - perhaps something else was intended for one of them - but I have transferred into the question what you posted. || I have also created an answer based on the comment which you confirmed to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Statement from the OP - *[msch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/343708/msch)* - in a now-deleted comment:

> {...} Dave tweed answered the question {...}

Here is the [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/672294/current-drop-with-capacitor#comment1790459_672294) by *[Dave Tweed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11683/dave-tweed)* so that it can be seen as the solution to the question:

> Isn't it obvious that C1 blocks the DC current in R3? C1 charges up to the "virtual" 2.5 V set by R4 and R5, and thereafter, only the AC signal drives current through R3. (It's basically a high-pass effect.)

---

<sub>(This question was reported solved by the OP, however no answer stating the the solution was written and accepted to make this clear. Therefore I have copied the solution (according to the OP) into this actual *answer*. I have applied the approach explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to post someone else's content as an answer. I have set it to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't *my* solution.)</sub>

Answer (score -3):

R3 and C1 are NEVER connected to the -input pin of an inverting opamp circuit.
They are used to set the voltage gain in a non-inverting opamp circuit.
[image: non-inverting opamp]

Comment: Saying "never" is a bit strong; it looks to me like some kind of compensation network, which you very well could put there if you want to modify the frequency response of the circuit. Regardless, this has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: Now we have a complete schematic. The series resistor and capacitor at the -input of the bottom inverting opamp do not go to ground, instead they are the input resistor and coupling capacitor for the bottom inverting opamp when fed from the output of the top opamp.